# MongoDB - Add aggregate field in pipeline depending on all elements of an array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Given the following documents in a collection:

```json
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63f06283b80a395adf27780d"
  },
  "suppliers": [
    {
      "name": "S1",
      "duesPaid": true
    },
    {
      "name": "S2",
      "duesPaid": true
    }
  ]
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63f06283b80a395adf27780e"
  },
  "suppliers": [
    {
      "name": "S1",
      "duesPaid": true
    },
    {
      "name": "S2",
      "duesPaid": false
    }
  ]
}]
```

I would like to create an aggregate field in each document that does the following: If the `suppliers` array has at least 1 element and every element in that has the `duesPaid == true`, then add a field to the document `suppliersPaid = true`. Otherwise, add `suppliersPaid = false`. The resulting documents from the pipeline should look like this:

```json
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63f06283b80a395adf27780d"
  },
  "suppliers": [
    {
      "name": "S1",
      "duesPaid": true
    },
    {
      "name": "S2",
      "duesPaid": true
    }
  ],
  "suppliersPaid": true,
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "63f06283b80a395adf27780e"
  },
  "suppliers": [
    {
      "name": "S1",
      "duesPaid": true
    },
    {
      "name": "S2",
      "duesPaid": false
    }
  ],
  "suppliersPaid": false,
}]
```

I have tried the following pipeline:

```
[{$addFields: {
  suppliersPaid: {
    $and: [
      { $gte: [{ $size: "$suppliers" }, 1] },
      {
        suppliers: {
          $not: {
            $elemMatch: { duesPaid: false },
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}}]
```

and I get the following error:

> Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: Unrecognized expression '$elemMatch'

I've tried to eliminate the reliance on `$elemMatch` per the docs https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/#single-query-condition as such:

```
[{$addFields: {
  suppliersPaid: {
    $and: [
      { $gte: [{ $size: "$suppliers" }, 1] },
      {
        suppliers: {
          $not: {
            duesPaid: false
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
}}]
```

But this yields the incorrect result of setting `suppliersPaid` to true for both documents, which is incorrect.

Note: I would like to avoid using any sort of JS in this code i.e. no `$where` operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second condition:

1. `$eq` - Compare the result from *1.1* to return an empty array.

   1.1. `$filter` - Filter the documents from `suppliers` containing `{ duesPaid: false }`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      suppliersPaid: {
        $and: [
          {
            $gte: [
              {
                $size: "$suppliers"
              },
              1
            ]
          },
          {
            $eq: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$suppliers",
                  cond: {
                    $eq: [
                      "$$this.duesPaid",
                      false
                    ]
                  }
                }
              },
              []
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LTXB0qrFFQ2)